# Remove column from MongoDB documents using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb

I want to remove a column and its corresponding value from my document.

Current:

```
{
 _id:'2323',
 name:'xyz',
 isAdmin:true
}
```

Expected:

```
{
 _id:'2323',
 name:'xyz'
}
```

I want to remove the `isAdmin` property from all the documents.

Comment: maybe [this](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.14/getting_started/quick_tour/#updating-documents)  with unset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MongoDB query, use [`$unset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/)

```
db.collection.update(
  {},
  { "$unset": "isAdmin" }
)
```

In MongoDB .Net Driver, you can do as below:

```cs
FilterDefinition<User> filter = Builders<User>.Filter.Empty;

var update = Builders<User>.Update.UnSet(u => u.IsAdmin);
// OR
// var update = Builders<User>.Update.UnSet("isAdmin");

_collection.UpdateMany(
    filter,
    update
);
```

---

### References

[Basic Updates | MongoDB C# Driver Cheat Sheet](https://gist.github.com/a3dho3yn/91dcc7e6f606eaefaf045fc193d3dcc3#basic-updates)

[Update.Unset Method](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_Builders_Update_Unset.htm)